# How to select attributes in a relational database where I have to check multiple attributes?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, attributes, where-clause

I have a relational database and I have a table like this

```
         person1           age       job           gender
        +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
         p1                22        abc           m
         p2                42        bng           f
         p3                38        xyz           m
```

I must select the person in which he/she must have age='42',job='bng' and gender='f'

I used Like this

```
Select person1.*
where person1.age='42' and person1.job='bng' and person1.gender='f';
```

But I get nothing. So how to select the row?

Comment: You didn't mention the table name.  "Person1" is a column.  Is it also the name of you table?  If so, that's a *REALLY* bad idea: you should have unique names for different things...  ANYWAY: the syntax should be `select person1 from mytable where age=42 and job='bng' and gender='f'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `FROM` clause, and the string literals must be in `''` instead of double quotes. If the `age` is of data type numeric, remove the quotes around it, if not use `''`. Something like:

```
Select person1.*
FROM person1
where person1.age    = 42 
  and person1.job    = 'bng' 
  and person1.gender = 'f';
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/915b4/1).

This should give you the row:

```
| PERSON1 | AGE | JOB | GENDER |
--------------------------------
|      p2 |  42 | bng |      f |
```

Answer (score 1):

you are missing `From` in your query.if person1 is not your table name then 
use like

`Select tablename(whatever your table name).* from tablename(whatever your table name) where age=42 and job='bng' and gender='f';`